# valgrind/helgrind gets killed on stress test

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, tcp, valgrind

I'm making a web server on linux in C++ with pthreads. I tested it with valgrind for leaks and memory problems - all fixed. I tested it with helgrind for thread problems - all fixed. I'm trying a [stress test](https://code.google.com/p/httperf/). I'm getting problem when the probram is run with helgrind

```
valgrind --tool=helgrind ./chats
```

It just dies on random places with the text "Killed" as it would do when I kill it with `kill -9`. The only report I get sometimes from helgrind is that the program exists while still holding some locks, which is normal when gets killed.

When checking for leaks:

```
valgrind  --leak-check=full ./chats
```

it's more stable, but I managed to make it die once with few hundreds of concurrent connections.

I tried running program alone and couldn't make it crash at all. I tried up to 250 concurrent connections. Each thread delays with 100ms to make it easier to have multiple connections at the same time. No crash.

In all cases threads as well as connections do not get above 10 and I see it crash even with 2 connections, but never with only one connection at the same time (with including main thread and one helper thread is total of 3).

1. Is it possible that the problem will only happen when run with
   helgrind or just helgrind makes it more likely to show?
2. What be the reason that a program gets killed (by kernel?) Allocating too much memory, too many file descriptors?

I tested a bit more and I found out that it only dies when the client times out and closes the connection. So here is the code which detects that the client closed the socket:

```
void *TcpClient::run(){
  int ret;
  struct timeval tv;
  char * buff = (char *)malloc(10001);
  int br;

  colorPrintf(TC_GREEN, "new client starting: %d\n", sockFd);
  while(isRunning()){
    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 500*1000;
    FD_SET(sockFd, &readFds);
    ret = select(sockFd+1, &readFds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    if(ret < 0){
      //select error
      continue;
    }else if(ret == 0){
      // no data to read
      continue;
    }
    br = read(sockFd, buff, 10000);
    buff[br] = 0;

    if (br == 0){
    // client disconnected;
      setRunning(false);
      break;
    }

    if (reader != NULL){
      reader->tcpRead(this, std::string(buff, br));
    }else{
      readBuffer.append(buff, br);
    }
    //printf("received: %s\n", buff);

  }
  free(buff);

  sendFeedback((void *)1);
  colorPrintf(TC_RED, "closing client socket: %d\n", sockFd);
  ::close(sockFd);
  sockFd = -1;

  return NULL;
}
// this method writes to socket
bool TcpClient::write(std::string data){
  int bw;
  int dataLen = data.length();

  bw = ::write(sockFd, data.data(), dataLen);
  if (bw != dataLen){
    return false; // I don't close the socket in this case, maybe I should
  }
  return true;
}
```

P.S. Threads are:

1. main thread. connections are accepted here.
2. one helper thread which listen for signals and sends signals. It stops signal reception for the app and manually polls the signal queue. The reason is because it's hard to handle signals when using threads. I found this technique here in stackoverflow and it seams to work pretty fine in other projects.
3. client connection threads

The full code is pretty big, but I can post chunks if someone is interested.

**Update:**

I managed to trigger the problem with only one connection. It's all happening in client thread. This is what I do:

1. I read/parse headers. I put delay before writing so the client can timeout (which causes the problem).
2. Here the client timeouts and leaves (probably closes socket)
3. I write back headers
4. I write back the html code.

Here is how I write back

```
  bw = ::write(sockFd, data.data(), dataLen);
  // bw is = dataLen = 108 when writing the headers
  //then secondary write for HTML kills the program. there is a message before and after write()
  bw = ::write(sockFd, data.data(), dataLen); // doesn't go past this point second time
```

**Update 2: Got it :)**

gdb sais:

```
Program received signal SIGPIPE, Broken pipe.
[Switching to Thread 0x41401940 (LWP 10554)]
0x0000003ac2e0d89b in write () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
```

Question 1: What should I do to void receiving this signal.
Question 2: How to know that remote side disconnected while writing. On read select returns that there is data but data read is 0. How about write?

Comment: did you have a look at your logs/dmesg? Sounds like it got OOM killed

Comment: checked. dmesg -> nothing, syslog -> nothing. Well there was one segfault in dmesg, but I remember that in earlier stage of development and it's fixed. I managed to track the problem and repeat it - read update in question

Comment: Valgrind sometimes dies like that and np one seems to know why. It's probably a kernel bug/feature. Can you try a different series kernel?

Comment: I could but I found the problem. It's not valgrind this time, it's SIGPIPE signal. I thought I handled all signals that terminate the program, but I forgot SIGPIPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I just had to handle the SIGPIPE singal and write returned -1 -> I close socket and quit thread gracefully. Works like a charm.

I guess the easiest way is to set signal handler of SIGPIPE to SIG_IGN:

```
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

Note  that first write was successful and didn't kill the program. If you have similar problem check if you are writing once or multiple times. If you are not familiar with gdb this is how to do it:

```
gdb ./your-program
> run
```

and gdb will tell you all about signals and sigfaults.